# When running private Docker repository, is it possible to share images with the local docker deamon

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-registry-mirror

## Background

We are running a `local` `Docker repository` inside a machine that is running `Docker.`

I'm trying to find out:

### Question

Do the `local repository` and the daemon, share same images and, therefore, does not increase the disk usage. Or, for every image X with size Y(MB), the fact that X in both the `local repo` and the `demon` X takes 2Y(MB)?

Thanks

### EDIT 1

Is it possible to `force` the `local repository` to share its `images` with the `daemon`?

Answer (score 1):

Well thought question. Answer from my experience is it must store separately. So when you do `docker rmi` images your local images must get removed not the ones from repository, even though you have hosted your repository on local, its still a repository. 
There are ways to test this by yourself. 
    - See whether pulls are faster  - i mean blazing faster when you do from daemon.
    - Perform `docker rmi IMAGE` and pull again, see whether the image gets pulled.
    - Delete the image from your repo, and see `docker images` lists it.